# How to change the width or alignment of an editor element according to the number of columns (Vaadin)

Tags: css, grid, alignment, vaadin, width

I am trying to **change** the `width` **or** `aligment` of `editorComponent` - `textField/integerField` in `non-buffered grid`.

The `problem` is with `textfield/integerField` width, if there are **more than 8 - 9** `columns`.

**7 columns:**

[image]

**10 columns:**

[image]

If there are **more** `columns`, the `textFields/integerField` starts to connect to each other

Full program:
https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-with-map

The main part, where the elements are created:

```
IntegerField integerField = new IntegerField();
binder.forField(integerField).bind(map -> map.get("col" + index),
                (map, value) -> map.put("col" + index, value));
grid.addColumn(map -> map.get("col" + index))
                .setEditorComponent(integerField).setHeader("Col " + index);
```

So I tried to align it, but it doesn't works

```
IntegerField integerField = new IntegerField();
integerField.getElement().getStyle().set("margin-left", "auto");
integerField.getElement().getStyle().set("margin-right", "auto");
binder.forField(integerField).bind(map -> map.get("col" + index),
                (map, value) -> map.put("col" + index, value));
grid.addColumn(map -> map.get("col" + index))
                .setEditorComponent(integerField).setHeader("Col " + index);
```

Or if I set the max width of element, it doesn't works too

```
IntegerField integerField = new IntegerField();
integerField.setMaxWidth("20");
binder.forField(integerField).bind(map -> map.get("col" + index),
                (map, value) -> map.put("col" + index, value));
grid.addColumn(map -> map.get("col" + index))
                .setEditorComponent(integerField).setHeader("Col " + index);
```

Any ideas how to set the width or alignment automatically ? Or how to set the width of `textField/integerField` by column width ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be as simple as setting:

```
integerField.setWidth("100%");
```